# Delphi program suddenly won't post query changes

Tags: delphi

I have Delphi application that has been in production for several years now and recently a specific piece of code has stopped working.  In the `OnClose` event for the form I have the following:

```
procedure TfrmPublicEmpInfo.FormClose(Sender: TObject;var Action: TCloseAction);  
var
  i : integer;  
  strWorkDays : string;  
begin  
  If cbMonday.Checked then strWorkDays := strWorkDays + 'Mo';  
  If cbTuesday.Checked then strWorkdays := strWorkDays + 'Tu';  
  If cbWednesday.Checked then strWorkdays := strWorkDays + 'We';  
  If cbThursday.Checked then strWorkdays := strWorkDays + 'Th';  
  If cbFriday.Checked then strWorkdays := strWorkDays + 'Fr';  
  If cbSaturday.Checked then strWorkdays := strWorkDays + 'Sa';  
  If cbSunday.Checked then strWorkdays := strWorkDays + 'Su';  
  if strWorkDays <> '' then    
  begin  
    qryPubEmployees.Edit;  
    qryPubEmployees.FieldValues['OCCUPATION'] := strWorkDays;  
  end;  

  dtpPEEndTimeChange(self);   
  dtpPEStartTimeChange(self);  

  For i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do  
  begin  
    If Components[i] is TQuery Then  
      with Components[i] as TQuery do  
      begin  
        if State = dsEdit then  
        post;  
      end;  
  end;  
end;
```

It gets to the `dtpPEEndTimeChange(self)` call which is this:

```
procedure TfrmPublicEmpInfo.dtpPEEndTimeChange(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  qryPubEmployees.Edit;  
  dbePEEndTime.Field.Value := StrToInt(FormatDateTime('HHMM', dtpPEEndTime.Time));  
end;
```

while in this function the program calls Windows.pas and gets stuck in:

```
function GetTickCount; external kernel32 name 'GetTickCount';
```

it never posts the changes to the record.

Does anyone know if any Windows updates may have caused this malfunction?  We are currently on Windows XP Professional Version 5.1 SP 3.

Comment: The obvious question is "what changed"?  If the only thing that has changed in your environment is windows updates then the answer is "Yes the windows updates are to blame".  Try uninstalling the most recent one by one and testing ..?

Comment: No, Steve, the most recent thing to change isn't always the cause. It could be that the code has been wrong forever and the latest update finally fixed a bug that was allowing the wrong code to appear to work by accident.

Comment: Perhaps - but that does seem less likely.  And certainly reverting any updates will pinpoint the issue a little.

Comment: @Leslie what does it mean that it get stucked? Does the program freeze? Are you 100% positivie that nothing has been changed in this code?

Comment: use revision control to review changes since it worked.  start cutting stuff out of OnClose to see what you need to remove to make it stop hanging.  assume the problem is in the application's code--not windows' update.

Comment: I would first add a Try...Except around the qryPubEmployees.Edit and dbePEEndTime and f.i. put a -1 in that field (or better still, the error nr). I would also do a Post immediatly after the Edit ... Field.Value lines. Do not think it's a Windows update which causes the problem too soon.

Answer (score 2):

GetTickCount returns Cardinal. If you are storing result to integer variable, it will result to integer overflow when your computer has been up for 25 days or so.
I'm just guessing, but that once was problem in our application.

Comment: From the Delphi help: 'The elapsed time is stored as a DWORD value. Therefore, the time will wrap around to zero if the system is run continuously for 49.7 days. To avoid this problem, use GetTickCount64.' For this reason, I would never use GetTickCount ...

Comment: @Edelcom: That is a bad idea in most cases, as using `GetTickCount64()` unconditionally will limit your software to Windows Vista, Server 2008 and later versions. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724411%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: This is a good insight, but not likely to be her problem, as she says it is "freezing" inside a kernel api call.  That sounds like stack corruption.